# Whats the difference between router actions and controller actions?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When should I be using router actions as opposed to using controller actions? I know they both serve different purposes but not sure why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, technically they serve the same purpose, it's more a matter of where you want actions to be handled/scoped.

Actions are bubbled in a very specific fashion.  From the dom they hit the associated controller, then that controller's associated route, then up the route tree (defined by the router mapping).  http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_action-bubbling

So if you think the action will never need to be used past the controller (aka you won't ever want to use it from some child route) then the controller is appropriate, if you think maybe a child route will want to trigger the parent's action then inside the route it goes.